# what is the difference when string == is used for comparison with in System.out.println() and in a if statement

Tags: java, string, immutability

```
String att = "siva";   
String ptt = "siva";

System.out.println("__________________________ptt.equals(att)_______"+ptt.equals(att));
**System.out.println("__________________________att == ptt________"+att == ptt);**   
if(att == ptt){   
    System.out.println("true");  
}else{   
    System.out.println("false");   
}
```

On my log i find the following output:

```
__________________________ptt.equals(att)_______true   
**false**   
true
```

here if you look at the java code and the log (in bold). there is a difference .

1. In the print statement i have given a long underscore with some text. it is not appearing.
2. att==ptt gives false when it is given with in print statement. and true when it is given in if condition.

already i know,
what is a reference and what is a object.
what is difference between att==ptt and att.equals(ptt).
immutability of a string.

but just what to know why it returns false and true when printed in different forms? and why the text that i have entered in the print statement not reflected in log?

please correct it if am wrong.. or if any extra input is required.

Comment: What @Abimaran said is correct... to print `true` in `println()` statement surround `att == ptt` with parentheses like `(att == ptt)`, where parentheses takes precedence before concatenation

Comment: To understand what is happening you should read about operator precedence http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In the print statement i have given a long underscore with some text.
>   it is not appearing.

Because, those underscore was concatenated with `att` and checked to referential equality(`==`) with `ptt`, and prints false, becuase concataneted String and `ptt` are not referentially equal. Change it like following to get you desired output

```
System.out.println("__________________________att == ptt________"+(att == ptt));
```

> `att==ptt` gives false when it is given with in print statement. and
>   true when it is given in if condition.

Both are referring same String literal in String constant pool, but, in the previous case(your 1st question), `att` was concatenated with the under score and compared with `==`

Answer (score 2):

Change the Line to:

```
System.out.println("__________________________att == ptt________"+(att == ptt));
```

Now your output will be as expected. First it compare the reference of `att` and `ptt` and then it is printed. You only forgott the parentheses . Now the result will be the same like in the if-statement. And the result is `true` because you are using String literals to assign the value `"siva"`. Internally this literals got the same reference. If you creat String objects like `new String("siva")` the output of your code will be false because you are comparing the reference with `==` and if you creat two objects the reference is different.